# Implementing Moment.js and Moment Timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have a jsfiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/JJJBG/).

It's blank because what I'm trying to do isn't working...

I have called the appropriate external scripts.

I'm trying to implement this incredible library into my site, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Ultimately, I need to display timezones for different parts of the United States, based on the state clicked on.

I've included the core library, the moment-timezone library and my moment-timezone-data file. Here's how the data file looks (pulled it from **[Timezone Data Builder](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/)**)

```
moment.tz.add({
    "zones": {
        "America/Los_Angeles": [
            "-7:52:58 - LMT 1883_10_18_12_7_2 -7:52:58",
            "-8 US P%sT 1946 -8",
            "-8 CA P%sT 1967 -8",
            "-8 US P%sT"
        ]
    },
    "rules": {
        "US": [
            "1918 1919 2 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1918 1919 9 0 8 2 0 0 S",
            "1942 1942 1 9 7 2 0 1 W",
            "1945 1945 7 14 7 23 1 1 P",
            "1945 1945 8 30 7 2 0 0 S",
            "1967 2006 9 0 8 2 0 0 S",
            "1967 1973 3 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1974 1974 0 6 7 2 0 1 D",
            "1975 1975 1 23 7 2 0 1 D",
            "1976 1986 3 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1987 2006 3 1 0 2 0 1 D",
            "2007 9999 2 8 0 2 0 1 D",
            "2007 9999 10 1 0 2 0 0 S"
        ],
        "CA": [
            "1948 1948 2 14 7 2 0 1 D",
            "1949 1949 0 1 7 2 0 0 S",
            "1950 1966 3 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1950 1961 8 0 8 2 0 0 S",
            "1962 1966 9 0 8 2 0 0 S"
        ]
    },
    "links": {}
});
```

**And here's the call to the script...**

```
<body>
    <script>
        moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("h:mm a")
    </script>
</body>
```

Some guidance would be great here!

Comment: Hi, I'd be glad to help but the link you posted is not to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).  Whatever it is to is requiring a username and password, so I can't see it.

Comment: I completely apologize for that. I feel terrible. I've updated the link with the jsfiddle.

Comment: Still no go.  I think you are including external resources from your own web site that is password protected.  At any rate, it's probably just what I described in my answer below.

Comment: Oh... didn't realize you're the same guy as below. See my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could just be that you aren't doing anything with the output.  Try something like:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<script>
    var s = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("h:mm a");
    document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = s;
</script>
```

Of course, what you *actually* do with it will be dependent on your application.

Comment: Okay. That worked. I upvoted your answer for that, but I don't want a popup... I want it to simply display inside a div I created.

Comment: Updated.  This would be for any javascript.  There are other ways, such as jQuery.  But nothing special here for moment.js - it's just a string.

Comment: That ended up giving me a completely blank screen. I'm playing around with it now.

Comment: It works because you put  `var s = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("h:mm a");
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = s;` at the bottom... that makes sense now.